# Android: TabActivity, Creating Menu

Tags: android

i have created 3 tabs using the TabActivity. The class declaration is like this.

***public class ABTM extends TabActivity*** {

........ some code ..........

}

now i want to create a Menu with three menu items. but the problem is that the

**@Override public boolean OnCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

}**

gives error. It says that i should remove the @Override. When i remove the @Override the error is gone and the application runs fine but pressing the menu button does nothing.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you post the code for OnCreateOptionsMenu()?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a case issue.  The method name should be `onCreateOptionsMenu` with a lower case first letter.  The purpose of `@Override` is specifically to warn you if the method that you are attempting to override does not exist in the superclass.  By removing `@Override` you are ignoring the cause of the problem and declaring a differently named method, which is why it doesn't get invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Menu imported.  Whenever I get this error when overriding methods, it's because the type of one (or more) parameters hasn't been imported.  Unfortunately, the result is that Eclipse can't make sense of what you're trying to override and throws an error stating this instead of first throwing an error saying it doesn't know what "Menu" is.